# strange behavior after if ... eql?... statement

Tags: ruby

I'm new to Ruby and was trying to do one simple exercise.
I need to find the longest symmetric range inside an array.
My code is:

```
index_start = index_end = nil
max_length = 0
array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,6,5,4,3,2,1]
length = array.length
array.each_with_index do |outer_element, outer_index|
  array.reverse.each_with_index do |inner_element, inner_index|
    if outer_element.eql? inner_element
      end_index = length - 1 - inner_index
      tmp_array = array[outer_index..end_index]
      if tmp_array.eql? tmp_array.reverse and max_length < tmp_array.length
        index_start, index_end = outer_index, end_index
        max_length = tmp_array.length
      end
    end
  end
end
print max_length, "\n"
print index_start,' ', index_end, "\n"
unless max_length.eql? 0
  print array[index_start..index_end]
end
```

The problem is this: after the second iteration by the inner loop, the `inner_index` variable becomes equal to 11, while it has to be 1 and this is happening after the `if outer_element.eql? inner_element` statement.

I'm a little bit confused about what I'm doing wrong.

Excuse my English and Ruby, I'm new to both. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: How is your title related to your question?

Comment: sorry, my mistake. changed it to make more clear)

Comment: Is there any reason to use `eql?` instead of the conventional `==`?

Comment: actually, no, there is no reason. Just very often I see using .eql? method instead of == in examples. I know the differences between them, so the using == instead of eql? method is more proper in not specific cases?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a

```
max_length = tmp_array.length
```

in the case you found a new longest symmetric sub-array.

With the current code, `max_length` is always 0 and the last one-element sub-array (`[1]`) is symmetric and longer than 0.

So the code should be:

```
...
if tmp_array.eql?tmp_array.reverse and max_length < tmp_array.length
  index_start, index_end = outer_index, end_index
  max_length = tmp_array.length
end
...
```

Comment: @MansurFattakhov: But what is the problem now? Now it is working, isn't it?

Comment: yes, thanks. the thing is, when I debug the code, on the second iteration after if outer_element.eql? inner_element statement the inner_index variable not going by iteration: here`re values by iterations:
1st: 0
2nd: 7
3rd:13

Comment: @MansurFattakhov: I guess you set your breakpoint into the `if`. SO it will only be hit if the condition is fulfilled which would be at `inner_index` 0 and 11 (for `outer_index` == 0), then 1 and 10 and so on.

Comment: I put my breakpoint into `array.reverse.each_with_index do |inner_element, inner_index|` before if, do you think it could be a reason?

Comment: Then, I  don't know. It should not behave as described and it does not here.